# Java Web Application specify entry point

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, netbeans

I have some Java Web Application and now it's starting from index.jsp page.
I have my own class with following code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class EntryPointClass extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException
    {
      ....
    }
}
```

My MANIFEST.MF file looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-class: asap.vito.mobileapi.EntryPointClass
```

But anyway, after deleting index.jsp I have a 404 error.

What should I change to start my app directly from my java class?

Thank you.

Comment: Change config in web.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all its a servlet not simple java class...
You should give its mapping into the web.xml and then u can access it directly

give this type of mapping for your servlet

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>entryPointClass </welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>EntryPointClass </servlet-name>//servlet name here
            <servlet-class>examples.EntryPointClass </servlet-class> // packagename.servletclassname
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>EntryPointClass </servlet-name>// servletname
            <url-pattern>/entryPointClass </url-pattern>  // url parttern by which you will access your servlet
        </servlet-mapping>
```

To access this from server use projectname/urlpattern

Answer (score 1):

Change/Add Welcome File Tag Element in Web.xml Configuration or Use Servlet Mapping.