# How do I set http entry point to my java application

Tags: java, http

I would like to create an entry point for my Java application where I am able to call my program with different inputs, preferrably over HTTP.
I am not sure if I should use Servlet like here
[Java Web Application specify entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806120/java-web-application-specify-entry-point)
or there is simplier way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a simple web framework like javalin.

https://github.com/tipsy/javalin

Example

```
    Javalin app = Javalin.create().start(7000);
    app.get("/hello", ctx -> ctx.result("I am alive"));
```